# I want to ask grammar about "many resulting"

Tags: grammar

1. But the Mount St. Helens cataclysm was only one in a long time of spectacular volcanic eruptions that have occurred over the past hundreds years, many resulting in far more damage and loss of life.

I have understood what the sentence means, but I feel that need to add noun between "many" and "resulting".

Comment: The only words that could reasonably be added are _of them_ (where _them_ refers to earlier eruptions). What noun to you want to add?

Comment: In my opinion,”many” is adjective, so need to add a noun so that we can know adjective describe sth, and I  am wondering why is “resulting” not result

Comment: The sense is that **many** of the earlier eruptions of Mount St. Helens **have resulted** in far more damage than the recent one did. **Many** is a noun and **resulting** acts as an adjective.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you!!! I totally understand that now.